# How to get number of current day of week using carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the current day as a number for example lets assume that the week starts from Saturday =1 so, today(Sunday) =2; using Carbon;

```
 $dt = Carbon::now()->week()->currentDay();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get with: `Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek`

[Carbon - Getters documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

Comment: Or, use `Carbon::now()->dayOfWeekIso` to get day number starting from Monday as **1** until Sunday as **7**.